# How to customize default browser error message on field type validation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form with an input of type=url. I want to show a custom message when the user tries to submit an invalid URL.

But, I don't want to re-check the url validity with custom javascript. I want the browser to validate, but I want a custom message. Is there an event I could listen to or some other property I could customize?

Comment: [setCustomValidity?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity)

Comment: Do you mean customizing the error message or the look of the message? Also what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `title` with the [pattern validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url#Pattern_validation):

```html
<form action="" method="get">
  <input id="myURL" 
        name="myURL" 
        type="url"
        required 
        pattern=".*\.myco\..*"
        title="The URL must be in a Myco domain">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to prevent the browser from displaying the builtin message when user submits the form, not at least on Firefox.

Comment: It does. It does it on stages where the first one is to validate it is a valid url and the second is if it matches the pattern.